# PHP: Quick sort code keeps saying: Warning: array_merge(): Argument #3 is not an array in

Tags: php, arrays

I am learning about sorting algorithms and I am trying this code:

```
function quicksort($array){
              if(count($array) == 0){
              return array();
              }

              $pivot = $array[0];
              $left = array();
              $right = array();

                  for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){
                      if($array[$i] < $pivot){
                        $left[] = $array[$i];
                      }
                      else{
                        $right[] = $array[$i];
                      }

                      return array_merge(quicksort($left), array($pivot), quicksort($right));
                  }

              }
              $sorted = quicksort($data);
```

However, when trying to run it - it gives me:

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #3 is not an array in - on line 21

Any reason for this?

Comment: You have to do more research before posting questions on SO. I did a search on sort algorithms in PHP and you basically posted [this snippet](http://andrewbaxter.net/quicksort.php)!

Comment: You are missing a `)` after the third parameter!

Comment: @yardpenalty not really that one but from other site. 
I am going through few different sorting methods and trying to remember code then rewrite it from what I remember.

Comment: Ok, just make sure you give reference to code snippets you borrow. :-)

Comment: @yardpenalty if it's say quicksort algorithm, wouldn't all writted snippets/examples be same anyway though?

Comment: True. They are all the same in concept. Just make sure you do put forth ample amount of effort prior to posting. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're returning inside the loop, you need to move that statement outside the loop.

```
<?php
function quicksort($array){
    if(count($array) == 0){
        return array();
    }

    $pivot = $array[0];
    $left = array();
    $right = array();

    for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++){
        if($array[$i] < $pivot){
            $left[] = $array[$i];
        }
        else{
            $right[] = $array[$i];
        }
        // remove return that was here
    }

    // and move it outside the loop here
    return array_merge(quicksort($left), array($pivot), quicksort($right));
}

$data = [3,4,2,1];
print_r(quicksort($data));
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => 1
>     [1] => 2
>     [2] => 3
>     [3] => 4
> )
> ```

Comment: He is also missing a parenthesis. He basically grabbed this code snippet from [here](http://andrewbaxter.net/quicksort.php) and put forth zero effort in solving the problem.